# Unable to show the form with modal fade out in Django

Tags: django, modal-dialog

I have confused how to upload file to DB by form in a modal, as it did not show the form after I clicked the button for modal fade out.

views:

```
def user_info(request):
user = request.user
orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=True).order_by('-start_date')
order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
context = {
    'user': user,
    'orders': orders,
    'order_items': order_items,
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'userinfo.html', context)

def upload_page(request, id):
   order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=id)
   form = Upload_File(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=order)
   if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            order.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Succeed')
            return redirect('user_info')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Failed')
            return redirect('user_info')
else:
    form = Upload_File()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'order': order
    }
    return render(request, 'payment_upload.html', context)
```

template including modal:

```
{% for order_item in orders %}
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#upload-{{ order_item.id }}">
 Open Modal</button>
{% endfor %}
```

modal template:

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'upload_page' id=order_item.id %}">
{% csrf_token %}

        {{ form }}

        <button class="form-group btn btn-success" type="submit">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is, are there any error message displayed or what is the point?

Comment: the form unable to show on modal

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, But inside your ***def user_info(request):...*** I can't see any import for `form` or any kind of declaration.

Which you are using inside your context

```
context = {
    'user': user,
    'orders': orders,
    'order_items': order_items,
    'form': form
}
```

You should declare your

> form = Upload_File(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=order)

at the top of the all `def()` so it can be accessed globally by all the other `def() methods`.